# JS/w2ui : How to add children to grid with w2ui JavaScript UI library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, w2ui

I have a nested grid based on w2ui library.
I'm trying to add a children to a specific row but I can't make it work.
Here is my code :

```
const id=  w2ui['grid1'].getSelection()[0];
const node= w2ui['grid1'].get(id);
w2ui['GRIDNAME'].get(id).w2ui.children.push({data_To_Insert})
w2ui['GRIDNAME'].refresh();
```

Could someone explain to me why is this not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a trick :

```
const id=  w2ui['grid1'].getSelection()[0];
const node= w2ui['grid1'].get(id);
if(typeof node.w2ui ==="undefined"){
   node.w2ui={};
   node.w2ui.children=[];
 }
node.w2ui.children.push('childToPush}) 
w2ui['grid1'].collapse(id);
w2ui['grid1'].expand(id);
```

This is a working solution, there may be others.